# How to Insert data android to C# restfull webservices

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf-web-api

I tried to connect cross platform Android to C# wcfrestfull webservices `My Que`. How to insert data Android to Wcfrestfull webservices?

Comment: Can you show what you have been tried.

Comment: If u want tutorial find on google . and after that if u get any error then update question .

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Create simple .NET WCF service
With function GetPersons() we get data from SQL 2008 database, and return them as generic list.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

using MB.AndroidWCF.DataAccessLayer;

namespace MB.AndroidWCF
{
public class Service : IService
{
    public List<spGetPersonsResult> GetPersons()
    {
        // Get data with DLINQ
        return new dbAndroidWCFDataContext().spGetPersons().ToList();
    }
 }
}


IService.cs
Note that the spGetPersonsResult is SQL stored procedure accessed with  DLINQ.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

using MB.AndroidWCF.DataAccessLayer;

namespace MB.AndroidWCF
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetPersonsJSON")]
    List<spGetPersonsResult> GetPersons();
 }
 }


The WCF service returns data in JSON format like this:

{"GetPersonsResult":[{"ID":1,"FullName":"Matija Božičević"},
{"ID":2,"FullName":"Al Pacino"},
{"ID":3,"FullName":"Clint Eastwood"}]}


2. Connect Android application with .NET WCF service, get some data in JSON format, and show data in Android's ListView

MainActivity.java

package AndroidWCFApp.package;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    GetPersons();
}

public void GetPersons() {
    ArrayList<String> persons = FromJSONtoArrayList();

    ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, persons));
}

public ArrayList<String> FromJSONtoArrayList() {
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        // Replace it with your own WCF service path
        URL json = new URL("http://192.168.1.1:9020/Service.svc/GetPersonsJSON");
        URLConnection jc = json.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));

        String line = reader.readLine();

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("GetPersonsResult");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);

            // "FullName" is the property of .NET object spGetPersonsResult, 
            // and also the name of column in SQL Server 2008
            listItems.add(jObject.getString("FullName"));
        }

        reader.close();

    } catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return listItems;
}
}



And thats it! Plain and simple!
```